# iOS Universal Links opens Safari and the app in the background

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have implemented iOS universal Links as documented by Apple, hosting my apple-app-site-association file within the root of my server. I can see that the link is working correctly, when touched on the test device it does confirm Open the App Title in the context menu. However, on tap, the link will open the app first, and then Safari to the relevant page on my website, putting the app on the background.

Has anyone encounters same issue? If so, is there a way I can work around it? Here is my sample apple-app-site-association file:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "comment": "Some comment.",
            "appID": "TEAMID.com.companyname.bundleidentifier.ios",
            "paths": [
                "NOT /_/*", "/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course I have masked the TEAMID and the bundle id in this sample

Comment: How are you handing the incoming url in your app?  You can't simply call `open` on it. If an iOS app calls `open` on a universal link it is assumed that the app can't handle that link and it wants to open it in the web browser. You need to route directly to the relevant screen in your app in response to the incoming url

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 the iOS app is handling the url correctly, the app is actually opened by the link but put in the background, and the Safari web page coming to the foreground. I should have noted that the app is installed in the device via TestFlight, so I am wondering whether this is a TestFlight artefact

Comment: No, if your app is opening and then safari is opening then your app is causing Safari to open.  [edit] your question to show how you handle the incoming link.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 indicated, the issue was app side and how we are handling the link. This is now resolved, but as reference here is sample code handling the Universal link:

```
// Universal links:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
   // App was opened from a Universal Link
   if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
       [self application:application openURL:userActivity.webpageURL sourceApplication:nil annotation:[NSDictionary dictionary]];
   }
   return YES;
}
```